# gcc / C++ Disable generation of vex instructions

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, valgrind

We are debugging memory issues with our large legacy app and would like to use Valgrind to track it down. The app uses the [ACE/TAO CORBA library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAO_(software)) however, Valgrind complains of illegal "vex" instructions in the library.

```
==29992== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29992== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29992== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29992== Command: DvMain
==29992==
DvMain. Version 6.0  Build 38B16
vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xC4 0xE2 0x7B 0xF7
==29992== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x5f37a4b.
==29992==    at 0x5F37A4B: ACE_Select_Reactor_Impl::bit_ops(int, unsigned long, ACE_Select_Reactor_Handle_Set&, int) (in /usr/local/dvstation/lib3p/ACE/libACE.so.6.2.7)
```

[In another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980501/c-code-stability-between-different-g-versions?noredirect=1#comment78921585_45980501), *[VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt)* suggested disabling AVX instructions with `-mno-avx`, which worked on some things. However, still have problems.

I've tried `-mno-sse2avx -mno-avx -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mno-sse4 -mno-sse4a` but Valgrind still complains of vex instructions in `::bit_ops()` (If you are interested, `bit_ops` is defined on [line 956 of this file](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/ACE-5.6.1/html/ace/Select__Reactor__Base_8cpp-source.html))

How do I disable completely the generation of VEX instructions so I can use Valgrind to debug?

Platform is 32-bit Centos 6, g++ 4.9.4

(please don't suggest moving to 64-bit. That's not an option with this product)

Reference:

Compile line for offending file:

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.9.4/bin/c++4.9  -mno-sse2avx -fvisibility=hidden 
-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fdiagnostics-color=auto 
-mno-avx -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mno-sse4 -mno-sse4a 
-O3 -march=native -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing 
-Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -D_GNU_SOURCE  
-c -fPIC -o .shobj/Select_Reactor_Base.o Select_Reactor_Base.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VEX is pretty new. Using an old architecture, e.g. `-march=pentium4` will disallow VEX instruction coding, but you keep SSE2.

Comment: @PaulFloyd: The term is overloaded, but here it clearly means the x86 VEX encoding. You can see this in "unhandled instruction bytes: `0xC4 0xE2 0x7B 0xF7`". 0xC4 is the x86 VEX prefix.

Comment: I didn't know about the VEX opcode prefix. On the Valgrind side, the message is not related to this. In VEX/priv/guest_x86_toIR.c there is `/* All decode failures end up here. */  vex_printf("vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: "`

Comment: @PaulFloyd: The _cause_ of the decode failure is that `0xC4 0xE2 0x7B 0xF7` instruction, which is an x86 VEX-encoded instruction that Valgrind fails to parse. By using `-march=pentium4`, GCC won't generate that `0xC4` instruction, avoiding the decode failure.

Comment: I agree that's a fine solution. I'd just like to make it clearer that the message from Valgrind is a generic one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use valgrind 3.12 from DTS instead, in the form of the `devtoolset-6-valgrind` package?

- [devtoolset-6](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-6/)

Support for AVX2 instructions was added in valgrind 3.9, so you might avoid recompiling your software.

Comment: 32-Bit Centos 6 only supports up to devtools-3.  The release notes for valgrind 3.9 say "Support for Intel AVX2 instructions.  This is available only on 64 bit"...

Answer (score 1):

[VEX](https://archive.fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/valgrind_vex_future/attachments/slides/1842/export/events/attachments/valgrind_vex_future/slides/1842/valgrind_vex_future.pdf) is the Valgrind abstract machine representation. It is a fundamental part of Valgrind and you cannot turn it off. You either need to tell the compiler to emit machine code that your version of Valgrind understands or else upgrade to a more recent version of Valgrind that understands AVX.

AVX [dates from about 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) whilst the version of Valgrind that you are using was released in September 2012 and it probably hadn't added AVX support. Confusingly, these extensions also use a ["VEX" prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEX_prefix). In this case the "vex x86->IR" message from Valgrind refers to Valgrind's VEX not the AVX VEX prefix.

Comment: " You either need to tell the compiler to emit machine code that your version of Valgrind understands" is not so much an answer as a restatement of the question. The compiler is GCC; _how_ do you get GCC to emit x86 machine code without using x86 VEX ?

Comment: This was already answered. However if a future reader has an error like " vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes 0xf 0x5" and they find this question/answer then disabling the compiler VEX/AVX generation is not likely to help.